# Need help with using glossaries-extra package (Texpad, MacOS)

Tags: symbols, nomenclature, glossaries-extra, texpad

I am trying to work on a thesis following a template from my university, and I am having trouble making a 'Nomenclature' and 'Symbols' list. I am able to successfully make a 'Glossary' and 'Abbreviations' list, but for some reason I can't get the first two to work. I get the following message on each page where the Nomenclature and Symbols list should be:

[image: Error message.]

I've looked inside the .nomenclature-glo file, and there is an entry in there (the same way there is one for the lists that work). The same goes for the .symbols-glo file. I've made sure that the 'glossaries-extra' package is part of my distribution and is installed..as far as I can tell, that isn't the problem because the Abbreviations list is working (which is also part of the extras package). I am using Texpad on MacOS and I have tried the following settings:

[image: Texpad settings.]

By default (when I have Auto-Sense on), only 'Glossaries' is enabled. However, changing this setting also did not help. I have also noticed that Texpad recognizes only two index runs in my document, when I imagine that there should be four:
  [image: Number of indices.]

I've tried to search all over for this issue but haven't been able to find another post with a similar issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated! This is the code that I am working with:

```
% Define Glossary terms (This is properly done here, in the preamble. Could be \input{} from a file...)
% Main glossary entries -- definitions of relevant terminology
\newglossaryentry{computer}
{
name=computer,
description={A programmable machine that receives input data,
               stores and manipulates the data, and provides
               formatted output}
}

% Nomenclature glossary entries -- New definitions, or unusual terminology
\newglossary*{nomenclature}{Nomenclature}
\newglossaryentry{dingledorf}
{
type=nomenclature,
name=dingledorf,
description={A person of supposed average intelligence who makes incredibly brainless misjudgments}
}

% List of Abbreviations (abbreviations type is built in to the glossaries-extra package)
\newabbreviation{aaaaz}{AAAAZ}{American Association of Amature Astronomers and Zoologists}

% List of Symbols
\newglossary*{symbols}{List of Symbols}
\newglossaryentry{rvec}
{
name={$\mathbf{v}$},
sort={label},
type=symbols,
description={Random vector: a location in n-dimensional Cartesian space, where each dimensional component is determined by a random process}
}

\makeglossaries
```

Comment: This sounds like a Texpad issue not a Tex/LaTeX issue. Texpad has a help forum. Have you asked there? The developer has always responded to my posts, although his responses can take a while. Also, what happens when you compile with TeXShop (it is installed with TeXLive on macOS)?

Comment: @JeffreyJWeimer thank you for your response, I think you might have figured out the exact issue. I tried compiling with TeXShop and all 4 lists show up without any problems. So I guess it must be something with Texpad (that didn't occur to me because I didn't get any errors or warnings or anything like that). Would you kindly be able to point me to the help forum? All I can seem to find on their website are their blog posts and articles, but no options to post a question of my own.

Comment: It seems that TeXPad is explicitly calling `makeindex` on specific files (those associated with the default `main` glossary and possibly some of the other predefined glossaries provided by the base `glossaries` package) but it doesn't include the additional glossary provided by `glossaries-extra` or any custom glossaries (defined with `\newglossary`). It would be much better if it just had one tool that used either `makeglossaries` or `makeglossaries-lite`. I don't know anything about TeXPad, so I don't know how to change the configuration.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot thank you for your response, you're right that it seems to be an issue with Texpad more than anything else, as Jeffrey pointed out. Now I am just trying to figure out how to contact them about the issue and see what the problem is.

Comment: @DaveJ. If you get a response, it would be great if you could post an answer. I'm trying to [accumulate a list](https://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/buildglossaries) of all the various different front-ends and how they run the associated glossary tools.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot I'll be sure to post back once I have an anwswer :) thanks again for your help!